# Can someone help me find the 64.00 and send it to my account at Bitcoin Mining so they will release my funds?

Tags: exchange-fees

I sent 64.00 today to pay for my Exchange rate fee at Bitcoin Mining so they will release my funds to me. I tried Just Answer and my account has been closed so they couldn’t help. Can someone find my 64.00 and get it to Bitcoin Mining for me to show that I’ve paid and they will release my funds.

Comment: The people you have been communicating with are confidence tricksters, conmen, fraudsters, criminals. All winnings or profits they showed are fake. They stole the money you sent them. You will soon be contacted by criminals pretending to be Bitcoin recovery experts or pretending to have been helped by one. All fake designed to trick you into paying more and more fake fees.